# How to restrict the table/view access in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

Suppose I have 2 users available for the same project. The requirement is to restrict the table access in the same project to one user. How can it be managed it in Bigquery? what kind of access controls to be applied and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table level ACLS and set Bigquery `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` for users on the tables you wish to grant access. More details here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro

This approach doesn't require creating a separate dataset(as a workaround for table level access) for access control which use to be the case earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on requirements, and the strictness of them, this is what I do:

Grant the user access to a specific **table** within a dataset by granting the **BigQuery Data Viewer** role **at the table level**.
You can do this as follows:
-> Open the table in the console and click `Share`, then click `Add Principal`

[image: Share table by adding principal]

And to make it easier for the user to navigate the metadata of the table, such as schema, details and preview, I grant them the **BigQuery Metadata Viewer** role at the **dataset level**.
You should only do this of course if it is ok for the user to see which other tables within the dataset are there. (they can't see the data in the other tables, just the schema etc)
The advantage is that it will be easier for the user to see the schema and a preview of the data.

More info can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls